# How to bind a property to style.width in pixels?

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 2 and I've written the below code:

```
<div [style.width.px]="width">some texts </div>
```

I've also tried:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'width.px': width}">some texts </div>

export class MyComponent
{
 width: number = 150;
}
```

But it doesn't bind the width to the `div` element.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Works fine for me

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/SYFmGmwxiLegGP0ml3pv?p=preview)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styles: [`div { border: 3px solid red; }`]
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div [style.width.px]="width">some texts </div>

    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  width: number = 250;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

Comment: `{{` and `}}`. `[...]` and `{{...}}` are *never* used together. `[...]="xxx"` already defines that `xxx` is an expression. Try `[style.width] ="'calc(100% - ' + myWidth + ')'"`

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me:

```
<div [style.width]="paymentPerc+'%'"> Payment Recieved</div>
```

Answer (score 23):

For pixel unit

```
<div [style.width.px]="width"> Width Size with px</div>
```

Or

```
<div bind-style.width.px="width"> Width Size with px</div>
```

Other CSS units

```
<div [style.width.em]="width"> Width Size with em</div>
<div [style.width.pt]="width"> Width Size with pt</div>
<div [style.width.%]="width"> Width Size with %</div>
```

**Component**

```
export class MyComponent
{
   width: number = 80;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Check with same as below once:

```
<div [style.width]="width+'px'">some texts </div>

export class MyComponent
{
 width: number = 150;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the late answer. Most of the answers are good enough.

Let me add that if you want to use `px` and `%` at the same time, then you can do something like this;

```
<div [style.width]="myCondition == true ? MyHeightVariable+'px' : '33.33%' " > </div>
```

Or if you only want to set it in `px`;

```
<div [style.width.px]="myCondition == true ? MyHeightVariable : '33.33' "></div>
```

Or if you only want to set it in `%`;

```
<div [style.width.%]="myCondition == true ? MyHeightVariable : '33.33' "></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Just check styles of your div using inspect element.

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> or hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to open Inspect. Go to Elements Tab and find you div and check it's CSS properties, width is applied.

for Example:

```css
element.style {
    background-color: pink;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Otherwise add background color to  your div tag so It will easily visible to you.

.html file (template)

```html
<div [style.width.px]="width" style="background-color:pink"> some text </div>
```

Or

```html
<div [ngStyle]="{'width.px': width}" style="background-color:pink"> some text </div>
```

.ts file (component)

```js
export class MyComponent
{
    width: number = 150;
}
```