# Angular2 (v2.4.6) - Unable to bind data [style.height]="300"

Tags: angular

First of all thank you for help ,

I just downloaded angular-Cli and made a project - angular2 Version 2.4.6

Everything works fine except, I am not able to use Style Binding directly in HTML, My code is working fine with angular 2.2 Version, don't know what exactly happened in new version

```
<div   [style.width]="MYWIDTH" [style.height]="900" style="background-color: red" >
  Hello 
</div>
```

not working:  `[style.width]="MYWIDTH" [style.height]="900"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind a property to Style Width Pixel in Angular 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40930330/how-to-bind-a-property-to-style-width-pixel-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[style.height.px]="900"` or `[style.height]="'900px'"`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `[style.height]="'900px'"`?